# Autohotkey - #IfWinActivate block - send another key

Tags: autohotkey

In Foxit Reader, I'd like Autohotkey to respond to Numpad5 by double-clicking, then calling NumpadAdd. Individually, both work normally. But the first won't call the second. What is wrong? Thanks!

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; allow partial titles
#IfWinActive, Foxit
  Numpad5::
    Click 2
    Send {NumpadAdd} ; THIS DOESN'T REACT
  Return

  NumpadAdd::
    Send ^b ; create a bookmark
    ... do other stuff ...
```

Comment: Could you provide some feedback on the proposed solution(s). Did it help and solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about...

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; allow partial titles
#IfWinActive, Foxit
  Numpad5::
    Click 2
    GoSub, MyNumAdd
  Return


  MyNumAdd:
  NumpadAdd::
    Send ^b ; create a bookmark
    ... do other stuff ...


#IfWinActive
```

Comment: That could be simplified by using `GoSub, NumpadAdd`.  Hotkeys are labels too :-)

Comment: Nice to know about labels/Hotkeys.